# Reuse JSON Data within same JSON

Tags: json

Yep, as weird as it sounds... I have a JSON file, let's call it `styling.json`, and I need to recycle some of the references in it, so here is my original file

```
  "fontRef1": {
    "fontFamily": "{{fonts.mainFont}}",
    "fontWeight": "{{fonts.fontWeight2}}",
    "fontSize": "{{fonts.fontSize3}}",
    "lineHeight": "{{fonts.fontLineHeight7}}",
    "letterSpacing": "{{fonts.fontLetterSpacing1}}",
    "fontStretch": "normal"
  },
  "fontRef2": {
    "fontFamily": "{{fonts.subFont}}",
    "fontWeight": "{{fonts.fontWeight2}}",
    "fontSize": "{{fonts.fontSize1}}",
    "lineHeight": "{{fonts.fontLineHeight14}}",
    "letterSpacing": "{{fonts.fontLetterSpacing1}}",
    "fontStretch": "normal"
  },
  "fontRef3": {
    "fontFamily": "{{fonts.mainFont}}",
    "fontWeight": "{{fonts.fontWeight2}}",
    "fontSize": "{{fonts.fontSize3}}",
    "lineHeight": "{{fonts.fontLineHeight7}}",
    "letterSpacing": "{{fonts.fontLetterSpacing1}}",
    "fontStretch": "normal"
  }
```

and I would like to to be more like this

```
  "fontRef1": {
    "fontFamily": "{{fonts.mainFont}}",
    "fontWeight": "{{fonts.fontWeight2}}",
    "fontSize": "{{fonts.fontSize3}}",
    "lineHeight": "{{fonts.fontLineHeight7}}",
    "letterSpacing": "{{fonts.fontLetterSpacing1}}",
    "fontStretch": "normal"
  },
  "fontRef2": {
    "fontFamily": "{{fonts.subFont}}",
    "fontWeight": "{{fonts.fontWeight2}}",
    "fontSize": "{{fonts.fontSize1}}",
    "lineHeight": "{{fonts.fontLineHeight14}}",
    "letterSpacing": "{{fonts.fontLetterSpacing1}}",
    "fontStretch": "normal"
  },
  "fontRef3": {
    // Re-uses fontRef1
    ...fontRef1
  }
```

Is there something like this in JSON?